# Keep first 2 characters in column value and delete rest of the characters

Tags: mysql, sql

I want to keep first 2 characters of the column value and delete rest characters in mysql table.

```
+----------------+
| id | firstname |
+----------------+
| 1  | XYZUUIJ   |
| 2  | ABCF      |
+----------------+
```

Result :

```
+----------------+
| id | firstname |
+----------------+
| 1  | XY        |
| 2  | AB        |
+----------------+
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `substring()` to do it

```
UPDATE TABLE1 SET firstname=SUBSTRING(firstname,1,2);
```

Answer (score 4):

Use `left()` :

```
select id, left(firstname, 2) as firstname
from table t;
```

I think you don't need to delete or update the table, you can use `SELECT` statement with `LEFT()`

Answer (score 4):

```
update table set firstname=substr(firstname,1,2)
```